# Getting Error in "Create Transaction response"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i am working with authorized .net in ios

The mobile device is approved fine but i am getting the following error in "createTransaction" even i am not sending ant transaction key also

```
Create Transaction response
2012-07-26 18:23:40.600 Authorized[2095:207] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ErrorResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"><messages><resultCode>Error</resultCode><message><code>E00003</code><text>The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'name, transactionKey, sessionToken, password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.</text></message></messages></ErrorResponse>
namespace warning : xmlns: URI AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd is not absolute
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"
                                                                               ^
2012-07-26 18:23:40.601 Authorized[2095:207] Error = (null)
2012-07-26 18:23:40.601 Authorized[2095:207] Message: 
Message.code = E00003
Message.text = The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'name, transactionKey, sessionToken, password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
Message.description = (null)
2012-07-26 18:23:40.601 Authorized[2095:207] Messages: 
Messages.resultCode = Error
Messages.message = (
    "Message.code = E00003\nMessage.text = The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'name, transactionKey, sessionToken, password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.\nMessage.description = (null)\n"
)
2012-07-26 18:23:40.635 Authorized[2095:207] Messages: 
Messages.resultCode = (null)
Messages.message = (
)
2012-07-26 18:23:40.636 Authorized[2095:207] SplitTenderPayment = SplitTenderPayment.transId = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.responseCode = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.responseToCustomer = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.authCode = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.accountNumber = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.accountType = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.requestedAmount = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.approvedAmount = (null)
SplitTenderPayment.balanceOnCard = (null)
2012-07-26 18:23:40.637 Authorized[2095:207] CreateTransactionResponse: createTransactionResponse.anetAPIResponse = ANetApiResponse.refId = (null)
ANetApiResponse.messages = Messages.resultCode = Error
Messages.message = (
    "Message.code = E00003\nMessage.text = The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'name, transactionKey, sessionToken, password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.\nMessage.description = (null)\n"
)
```

Comment: It is because of special character in your xml response which the parser is not able to parse. Check your response string. Or use any string encoding mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Sandchitsignh points out, this looks like you are processing a response, that are not a fully valid xml response. Check the response thoroughly, and make sure no hidden, corrupt or unescaped characters have snuck their way in.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. This answer may helpful to any one because now i am not doing this. We left this concept